# problem with substack command

Tags: math-mode

Help me please with the following problem.

I want to write the following equation

```
$$\phi(U)_{\substack{\cap\\ \mathbb{R}}}$$
```

and my problem is `\cap` and `\mathbb{R}` don't appear under  `\phi`.

How can I do?

Comment: Is `\phi(U)` supposed to be a math operator?

Comment: it is a function applied to a set.

Comment: This seems an XY question: it would be better to explain what you want to achieve, probably an inclusion relation set vertically; the approach with `\substack` is not going to work and an `array` would be better.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

I can't tell if the items `\cap` and `\mathbb{R}` are supposed be typeset next to each other or one above the other. I suppose you may want one of the following two possibilities:

[image]

The `\mathclap` instruction lets its argument "protrude" to the left and right of `\phi` without introducing unnecessary whitespace on either side.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \mathclap and \substack macros
\usepackage{amsfonts}  % for \mathbb macro
\begin{document}
\[
\mathop{\phi}_{\mathclap{\cap\mathbb{R}}}(U) 
\quad
\mathop{\phi}_{\substack{\cap\\ \mathbb{R}}}(U) 
\]
\end{document}
```

Incidentally, don't use `$$` in a LaTeX document; use `\[` and `\]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your aims. However the task is easy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
\underset{\substack{\cap\\\mathbb{R}}}{\phi(U)}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want the size to decrease, use an `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}}
\phi(U)\\
\cap\\
\mathbb{R}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this the output you want to achieve?

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
  \mathop{\phi(U)}_{\substack{\cap\\ \mathbb{R}}}
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

You need to make the `\phi(U)` a math operator for the limits to work.

Another, maybe nicer solution is:

```
\begin{displaymath}
  \underset{\substack{\cap\\ \mathbb{R}}}{\phi(U)}
\end{displaymath}
```

Comment: There probably shouldn't be a line break after `\cap`; however, I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: @Mico I don't know. The question is rather unclear.

Comment: Can I modify such that what apper under \phi to appear more central? thanks!

Comment: @Iuli Ok, I've moved the `(U)` into the `\mathop`. How is this?